# Привязка нескольких Listbox к одному SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть несколько `ListBox` к которым привязываются разные коллекции. 
И есть панель со свойствами, где пользователь может редактировать выбранный элемент. Поэтому нужно сделать, что может быть выбран элемент только в одном из `ListBox`.

Я думал, что если сделаю свойство, в котором будет хранится выбранный объект:

```
public BaseAction SelectedElement
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedAction;
    }
    set
    {
        _selectedAction = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

и сделаю привязку к `SelectedItem`, то все будет работать, т.к. если `ListBox` не находит этот элемент у себя, то выделять нечего.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Bindig UserActions}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedElement}" />
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Bindig GroupActions}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedElement}" />
```

Но это не сработало. При выборе элемента в другом `ListBox` элемент из предыдущего не теряет выделения.

Подскажите, как реализовать задуманное?

Comment: @FoggyFinder, Спасибо! Действительно помогло. Когда-нибудь я выучу английский и смогу полноценно пользоваться поиском сам)) Оформите как ответ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самое просто решение использовать `SelectedValue` вместо `SelectedItem`

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Bindig UserActions}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedElement}" />
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Bindig GroupActions}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedElement}" />
```

Взято с ответа на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276933/wpf-single-selection-between-two-listboxes)